# combine more IF(OR Google sheet formula

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if

I have this problem , in a google sheet's cell I have put inside this formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(F21>"01/05/2022";F21<"31/05/2022");AND(G21=2;));$J$4;"errore");
```

and this run correctly.
but now I would combine this formula with another in the same cell i.e.

```
=IF(OR(AND(F21>"01/05/2022";F21<"31/05/2022");AND(G21=2;));$J$4;"errore");IF(OR(AND(F21>"01/06/2022";F21<"30/06/2022");AND(G21=3;));$K$4;"errore");
```

could you help me to made this without errore please? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(OR(AND(F21>"01/05/2022"; F21<"31/05/2022"); G21=2); $J$4; 
 IF(OR(AND(F21>"01/06/2022"; F21<"30/06/2022"); G21=3); $K$4; "errore"))
```

or for array:

```
=INDEX(IF((MONTH(F21:F)=5)+(G21:G=2); J4;
       IF((MONTH(F21:F)=6)+(G21:G=2); K4; "errore")))
```